# Ubuntu 16.04 Python3.6 installation

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04

I started using a computer at work that has Ubuntu 16.04 installed. Initially, Python3.6.8 was set as the version that was used if I entered the command 'python3' at the terminal. I updated Ubuntu using 'sudo apt-get update', installed miniconda and used the 'sudo apt-get autoremove' command. I followed the mini-tutorial on the anaconda website and one of the commands resulted in a warning about the pip version being old so I upgraded it inside a conda environment.

I noticed at some point that this error was occurring whenever I entered 'python3' at the commandline:

[image]

But as you can see, the default 3.5.2 version is there, but for some reason the 3.6.8 version doesn't seem to be there. These are the symlinks in /usr/bin and /etc/alternatives:
[image]
[image]

Is it safe for me to simply install Python3.6 using 'sudo apt-get install python3.6' and then the symlink will work correctly?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: You've found yourself in The Wormhole, where conflicting versions of Python and Pip are installed and it's hard to tell up from down. It's gonna be a pretty big pain to get out of it (Node is also notorious for stuff like this). I would uninstall all the Python runtimes you have to the best of your ability and start fresh with universe packages, i.e. `sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip` (or just get Python and use the `get-pip.py` script to install).

Comment: Ohhh damn. Thanks so much for the reply, I definately didn't want to hear this 'It's gonna be a pretty big pain to get out of it'. I wouldn't really care if it was my own system. This is literally the first time I sat down at this computer.... isn't uninstalling Python dangerous because Ubuntu internals rely on it heavily?

Comment: @Christian could I just make the python3 symlink in /usr/bin/ link to the python3.5 installation on there?

Comment: Sure, but `apt` won't break or anything, so you could always reinstall. I would be very cautious about toying with symlinks. It's important to be very intentional about what you're doing when it comes to installing/updating Python/Node etc. This is totally something you can recover from, but yeah, prepare to spend 3 or 4 hours dealing with this until you get a breakthrough. Someone can likely help you in here as well.

Comment: I know I just cautioned against it, but have you tried symlinking 3.6 -> `/usr/bin/python3`? You can always kill the symlink if it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see python3.6 in the /usr/local/lib directory. No I haven't tried symlinking the way you mentioned.